# User signature in PDF created by PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, electronic-signature

I have question regarding electronic signature.

I have to create some PDF that can by signed by the user and certified by certeurope.

But I have no idea, how to create it.

Do I have to create a stream of the pdf from php ? Then create a signature input, then validate it with certeurope, then create the final PDF ?

I don't need code, just some explanation.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: what do you mean, "electronic signature"? A picture of someone's ink-on-dead-trees signature? Or a full-blown cryptographic signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,

I forgot to answer this question.

It was easy, as it just need to curl the information to certeurope server.